ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _cext: Le module spécifié est introuvable
I write this
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [1, 2, 3, 4]
y = [10, 20, 25, 30]

plt.plot(x, y)
plt.xlabel('X-axis')
plt.ylabel('Y-axis')
plt.title('Simple Plot')
plt.show()

But an issue has arisen that I don't understand.
Is there a bug in the software or is it in the library?
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\DELL\OneDrive\Documents\python project\trying.py", line 12, in <module> 
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
  File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 276, in <module>
    _check_versions()
  File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 270, in _check_versions
    module = importlib.import_module(modname)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\Python312\Lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 90, in import_module 
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\kiwisolver\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from ._cext import (
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _cext: Le module spécifié est introuvable.  

I reloaded matplotlib and kiwisolver
but nothing changed

The matplotlib library has unmet dependencies on your computer (source: https://matplotlib.org dependencies).
A typical installation performed successfully would have installed these dependencies and expect a C++ compiler with support for C++17 to be installed on your machine.
If you're using Windows, matplotlib's instructions are:

Install Visual Studio Build Tools
Make sure "Desktop development with C++" is selected, and that the latest MSVC, "C++ CMake tools for Windows," and a Windows SDK compatible with your version of Windows are selected and installed. They should be selected by default under the "Optional" subheading, but are required to build Matplotlib from source.

You can also install visual C++ 2015 directly from Microsoft's website:
https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=48145
